# Extending Hashmap class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, hashmap

I want to build a totally reusable setter method for a class I'm using to submit a large collection of form data comprised of mostly strings and string arrays. It would be analogous to a map.set method. I am led to do this as opposed to just using a hashmap as I need the keys to be Immutable as they are critical to the parsing of the data on the API end. Could I extend the Hashmap class / object to create something like this, or can I actually just create a hashmap like this with Enum types for the keys? I've looked at the Typescript Docs and Hashmap information and it's not exactly conclusive.

Here's some pseudo code/commenting for what I'm envisioning:

```
value(newVal: string, varId: string) {
  this.varId = newVal; 
//find the key variable in the class matching VarId and give it the value newval 
//  if this.VarId doesn't exist, throw an error
}
```

Comment: You seem confused. For one thing, TypeScript doesn't add any APIs to JavaScript. JavaScript objects are associative data structures where keys can be a strings or symbols. JavaScript `Map`s are associative data structures where keys can be of any type.

Comment: ok so you're suggesting that I use a Hashmap with Enumerated Types as keys? I now understand that difference but which route should I take?

Comment: If I can be more clear about something specific or restructure my question in a manner that would actually help you help me, please let me know. If not, kindly see yourself out. Maybe instead of ridiculing my question and my intellect, guide me towards something helpful, or just don't comment. This is a website for sharing knowledge and helping others, not for telling them that they're "incoherent" and "nonsensical".

Comment: It was not my intention to suggest that you lack intelligence and I am sorry that I came off as dismissive. However, many statements in the question are problematic. I tried to explain but I'm not sure how to at this point. I think you need to learn more about JavaScript and I say this with no disrespect.